# DocC fails to generate parameters in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, docc

I am trying to build documentation for my app. However for some reason the parameters are not shown. Does any one have an idea what I am doing wrong?

example code

```
///meanRounds will calculate the mean of the rounds 
///
///(not functioning on the moment, working on mean2)
///
/// - Parameters :
///   - values: the array with values.
///   - times: the array with the times a value occurred.
///   - min:   the lowest occurence.
///   - max:   the highest occurence.
/// - Returns:
///   - averageValue : mean value
///
func meanRounds(values:[Int], times: [Int], min: Int, max: Int) -> (Double,Double,[Double]) {
    
    var averageValue = mean2(values: values, times: values.count)
    
    
    

    return (averageValue,2.0,[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0])
}
```

Below is the result, parameters are only presented with an 's', return value is completely ommitted
[image: Below the result, the parameters are only presented with an 's']

Comment: Removing the space between "Parameters" and ":" worked for me. Is this just a typo?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you are trying to write in the return value section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the space between `Parameters` and `:`

```
   - Parameters : << Incorrect

   - Parameters: << Correct
```

Comment: This solved indeed the Parameters. The return value was a stupid mistake (what you get when you try to build a dummy :-)